# Why does my button not perform the proper action?

Tags: java, jbutton, actionlistener

I created a little "calculator" using a GUI. But when I use my enter button, it always prints out the product of the two numbers regardless of the operator I press.

```
class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
   JTextfield firstN, secondN;
   JButton addButton, subButton, divButton, mulButton, enter;
   JLabel result;

   Calculator(){
      // here I initialized all the components and added buttons/ActionListeners
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      int first = Integer.parseInt(firstN.getText());
      int second = Integer.parseInt(secondN.getText());
      int value = 0;

      if(e.getSource() == addButton){
          value = first + second;
      }else  if(e.getSource() == subButton){
          value = first - second;
      }else if(e.getSource() == divButton){
          value = first/second;
      }else{
          value = first*second;
      }

      if(e.getSource() == enter)
         result.setText(value + "");
      }
```

Without the enter button, the calculator works fine. I tried a do-while loop but that turned out to be an infinite one..

I guess I got something wrong with the if/else Statements but one of the first 4 statements always gets executed so the last one should also work as far as I'm concerned...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` variable should not be declared inside the `actionPerformed` method. This way it is reset every time when you click a button. The enter button resets it as well. You got the product of the two number because it is the default branch of the first if statement. There should be only one if statement, and the value should be a class level field instead of local variable:

```
class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
   JTextfield firstN, secondN;
   JButton addButton, subButton, divButton, mulButton, enter;
   JLabel result;
   int value;
   Calculator(){
      // here I initialized all the components and added buttons/ActionListeners
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      int first = Integer.parseInt(firstN.getText());
      int second = Integer.parseInt(secondN.getText());


      if(e.getSource() == addButton){
          value = first + second;
      }else  if(e.getSource() == subButton){
          value = first - second;
      }else if(e.getSource() == divButton){
          value = first/second;
      }else if (e.getSource() == mulButton){
          value = first*second;
      }else if(e.getSource() == enter)
         result.setText(value + "");
      }
  }
```

Comment: worked perfectly! quickly offtopic: why is "value" reset every time a button is clicked? why should the variable be a class level field?

Comment: @marie.ellaZ It happens because the `actionPerformed()` method executes from the begging to the end every time when you click a button. So if it contains the line `int value = 0;` every click will set it to zero. If you want to keep the value between clicks you have to store it somewhere outside of this method, and a class level field is an obvious solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Its because your else clause will be called when (e.getSource() == enter) because the if and else if statements will be false. You could make it more like this:

```
      if(e.getSource() == addButton){
          value = first + second;
      }else  if(e.getSource() == subButton){
          value = first - second;
      }else if(e.getSource() == divButton){
          value = first/second;
      }else if(e.getSource() == mulButton){
          value = first*second;
      }else if(e.getSource() == enter)
         result.setText(value + "");
      }
```

Comment: with this solution the enter will set the result to zero

Comment: I agree with that, I did not really care for how he implements his value calculation as the question implied that the product was always calculated when enter was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Since the last else block **{ value = first*second; }** does not have an if condition, it will get executed not only when **e.getSource == mulButton** but also when **e.getSource == enter**.

A solution could be to replace the last else statement with this code:

```
} else if(e.getSource == mulButton) {
    value = first*second;
}
```